# Custom directories/listings in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm trying to create a directory in Joomla, which means, the user will have a form to add an entry (with custom fields) and the entry will show up in a page listing all added entries.

For now, I'm going with [SOBI](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/1113/details) which is a Joomla component handling all this.

**Question:**
I was wondering if there are any good alternatives, what I'm looking for is :

- Multi categories
- Custom fields
- Easily stylable forms and listings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should try some of the CCK solutions out there. They have all you asked for.

Some of them are:

- [ZOO](http://zoo.yootheme.com)
- [Flexicontent](http://www.flexicontent.org/)
- [K2](http://getk2.org/)

ZOO is IMHO the best, but has no frontend submission feature. Flexicontent and K2 do have it.

Answer (score 0):

I like Mosets Tree.  I've used it on several sites.